# How to show proper progress bars in vim command quickfix window

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using macvim, and when I run a shell command in vim's command mode like:

`:! yarn add redux`

I don't get proper progress bars, instead I get the following characters:

[image]

How can I get the output to show proper progress bars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters are what gives colors and effects (such as underlining) to outputs in shell. They need escape sequences in order to take effect.

The thing is, MacVim doens't have terminal in it and it doesn't do a good job at emulating one.

It doens't have all the features that a normal terminal would have, and that is why it doesn't support [ANSI escape sequence](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

There is a [plug-in](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) for vim that shows the terminal output in vim itself but like the description says in that page, it is no longer supported.

So if you want that screen to be visualized as they are intended to be, I would suggest you use vim in terminal (I tried the exact same code as yours and it worked fine).